# What is default name of Jta transactionManager that registers with <tx:jtaTransactionManager/> in spring and can I change it?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, weblogic, jta

In spring docks [Spring Framework 5.1.3.RELEASE Reference - Data Access](https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/spring-framework/5.1.3.RELEASE/reference/data-access.html) 
Says, "For standard scenarios, including WebLogic Server and WebSphere, consider using the convenient  <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>  configuration element. When configured, this element automatically detects the underlying server and chooses the best transaction manager available for the platform. "
When <tx:jtaTransaction/> used, What it's default name?
Can I change it's name?
If I need to use 2 transactionManagers in my project, I need to know it's name, so that I can point out the correct one.

```
@Transactional("jta")  
public void method test()  
...  
}  
@Transactional("local")  
public void method test1()  
...  
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a read of [the schema](https://springframework.org/tx/spring-tx.xsd) that defines the `tx` namespace. It states explicitly what is possible and what it does.

From said `spring-tx.xsd`

> Creates a default `JtaTransactionManager` bean with name "transactionManager",
> matching the default bean name expected by the "annotation-driven" tag.
> Automatically detects WebLogic and WebSphere: creating a `WebLogicJtaTransactionManager`
> or `WebSphereUowTransactionManager`, respectively.

As expected the name will be `transactionManager` and there is no way to change that as there are no attributes or further configuration on that element.